# Error in the Implementation of count function in Swift

Tags: swift, count

```
var test: String

test = "Hello"

count(test)
```

Error message: Cannot invoke count with an argument list of type '(Int)'

Answer (score 0):

```
test.characters.count
```

(Swift 2)

Answer (score 0):

The error makes no sense. Your code works in Xcode 6.3.2, but gives an error in Xcode 7. It must be a Swift 2.0 issue.

Answer (score -1):

If your version of Swift is before 1.2 it could be:

```
countElement(test)
```

If the version is 2.0 it is:

```
test.characters.count
```

Otherwise try:

```
Swift.count(test)
```